# How to pass SObject in future method?

Tags: future, queueable-apex

I am a beginner in programming world. I know the reason for error that we cannot use sobject as parameters in future method. Checking on forums i came to know that we can use set and then query record in method will solve the issue. However, I am not getting how to do this.

```
public class Opportunitysplithandler{  
  Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> oldotm;  
  Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> newotm;  
  List<OpportunitySplit> oppts = new List<OpportunitySplit>();  
  public Opportunitysplithandler(Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> oldtriggerotm, Map<Id, OpportunityTeamMember> newtriggerotm){  
    oldotm=oldtriggerotm;  
    newotm=newtriggerotm;  
}  
public void insertoppsplit (){  
  Set<Id> oppId=new set<Id>();
  for(OpportunityTeamMember opmem:newotm.values()){
         oppId.add(opmem.OpportunityId);
  }
  map<Id,Opportunity> mapIdByOpp=new map<Id,Opportunity>([select Id,Upsell_Percent__c from Opportunity where Id IN:oppId]);//query and store Opportunity data in Map 
    for(OpportunityTeamMember o: newotm.values()){  
      OpportunitySplit os1 = new OpportunitySplit();  
       os1.OpportunityId = o.OpportunityId ;  
       os1.SplitOwnerId = o.UserId;  
       os1.SplitPercentage = (mapIdByOpp.get(o.opportunityId)).Upsell_Percent__c;  
       system.debug('bbbbbbbbbb : '+ os1.SplitPercentage);  
       oppts.Add(os1);  
    }   
   insert oppts; //Do exception Handling here 
  }  
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How about running with `Queueable` instead of `@Future`?

Comment: @bigassforce is right. Future methods are pretty much deprecated in favor of Queueables [https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Queueable.htm]. Queueables support passing non-primitives.

Comment: Queueable is better than Future here are the links for both to learn
Queueable [link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_queueing_jobs.htm)
Future [link](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_invoking_future_methods.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/passing-objects-to-future-annotated-methods.html) example. basically you would need to work with JSON to pass SObject as parameter in future. If you have option, i would agree with @mattandneil to use `Queueable` interface.